# Brake (Formula T1S) extremely sticky for no reason

Tags: hydraulic-disc-brake

The [video](https://youtu.be/W6DEYRcdRa0) shows Formula T1S rear brake was last maintained/bled 6 months ago, on a 2015 mountain bike which I rode last 1 month ago: the brake functioned normally then (OK, it had a very slight rub). Since then the only action that bike saw was spending 5 hours on the roof of the car, and then it spent a month in a dry, slightly cool basement.

What's interesting is that the front brake was also sticking a bit, but after moving the bike to the warm balcony it's functioning more or less normally again. The brakes seem clean, no visible dirt in the levers or calipers.

What could be the reason of such extreme sticking? How do I start diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the pistons are not retracting well.  Could be dirt impacted from being on the car's roof (presumably it was driving somewhere.)

I would drop a wheel out, and remove the pads/spring.  Clean the inside of the caliper, then slightly advance the piston with a slow and gentle and careful squeeze of the lever.  Clean the exposed sides of the piston too.   Push the pistons back into the caliper with a suitable non-marring tool.  Do it again and see if the sides of the pistons are cleaner - repeat until clean.

Avoid over-extending the pistons.  If they come out of the caliper, it will make an enormous mess.  If they meet, you'll have a hard time separating them again.

It doesn't take much to make a piston sticky.

---

When reassembling, have a good look at the retraction/separating spring.  If it feels weak then it probably isn't pushing the pads back hard enough.  A bend can help, but ultimately you want to keep the good springs as spares, when you replace the pads.